# No options for run/debug TornadoFX app in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ide, tornadofx

I was following along with a tutorial on TornadoFX, using IntelliJ (Ultimate) as the development environment, and trying to get a "live edit" set up as described. To get this going, you need to tweak several parameters in the run/debug configurations window of IntelliJ.

But where the tutorial has all kinds of options that make the live-edit possible, I have literally none.

[image: Run/Debug Configurations dialog is somewhat lacking]

I've uninstalled/reinstalled the Tornado plugin and tried creating new apps, but no matter what I just get the black-screen-of-ennui. Anyone seeing different?

Running the 1.7.17.2 Tornado FX plug in IJ Ultimate 2020.3 (although I've tried the most recent and last three versions).

Comment: Please follow the related issue on plugin tracker: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-idea-plugin/issues/117